# `shift` in Bash but on arrays instead of arguments?

Tags: arrays, bash

Titel pretty much has it. I'm trying to do the `--options args` thing but instead of running `./command --option1 args --option2 args` I'm doing `./command '--option1 args --option2 args`.

```
array=( $1 )
POSITIONAL=()
while [[ ${#array[@]} -gt 0 ]]; do
key="${array[0]}"
case $key in
    --title)
        title="${array[1]}"
        echo 1
        shift
        shift
        ;;
    --artist)
        artist="${array[1]}"
        echo 2
        shift
        shift
        ;;
    *)      # unknown option
        POSITIONAL+=("${array[0]}") # save it in an array for later
        shift
        ;;
esac
done
set -- "${POSITIONAL[@]}" # restore positional parameters
```

In this code, `shift` doesn't work. Is there a way to use `shift` but on arrays?

Comment: Is there a close quote missing from the "I'm doing `./command '--option1 …'` part?  Or can you clarify that part?

Comment: Why are you doing it that way?  Will there ever be arguments after `$1`?  Did you consider using `set -- $1` to set positional arguments and then use (GNU) `getopts`?  Or otherwise be able to shift through the arguments?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually never thought of that, will try. Also I had to throw everything into `'` because some guy will try and Bash inject my scripts.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That worked. That worked very well. You should definitely make it an answer.

Comment: @dat: seems to me like a successful attack is more likely if you attempt to put all the arguments into one string, instead if leaving them separate. Why do you think it's safer?

Comment: I'm feeling lazy.  Accept the answer you've been given, which is about what I'd have written if I wasn't being lazy.  Then you can flag this 'no longer needed'.

Comment: @rici If I don't have quotation marks around them and regex all of the other quotation marks, they can just inject commands in by doing `string; rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` or some other commands.

Comment: @dat: So quote things properly.

Comment: The way you do it, with `array=( $1 )`, the untrusted input from the command line is *not quoted*. That's not easy to exploit, but it means the user doesn't get what they want. Suppose, for example, the user typed './command '--option1 "not --option2" --option2 no'`. What your script will see is equivalent to creating  `array=('--option1' '"Not' '--option2"' '--option2' 'no')`, which is not likely to lead to correct results. (And they might put a `*` or some other glob character into the command, too.) None of this is a problem if an argument is just an argument and you quote all expansions.

Comment: @rici I've seen this happening before and have properly dealt with it. Also `set -- $1` works.

Comment: @dat: I guess that depends on what you mean by "works". Script: `set -- $1; echo "$2";` Invocation: `./script.sh '--option "One word or four?"'` Output: `"One`. But, hey. It's your assignment. Do as you see fit. Good luck.

Comment: @rici Already dealt with this issue on the other side and it fits my purpose. No need to end it with a "Do as you see fit" to fake that you don't care.

Comment: @Dat: I don't care what you do. I do care what advice is put on this site which might mislead other people.

Comment: @rici Then why don't you put your single useful comment and put it down under the answer instead? If my question could somehow mislead people, then they most likely don't know what they're looking for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use array slicing to simulate shifting:

```
array=(aardvark baboon "clouded leopard" dolphin)
while (( ${#array[@]} ))
do
  echo "Animal: ${array[0]}"
  array=( "${array[@]:1}" )
done
```

And you if you have existing code that processes positional parameters, you can just set those from your array:

```
array=(aardvark baboon "clouded leopard" dolphin)
set -- "${array[@]}"
while (( $# ))
do
  echo "Animal: $1"
  shift
done
```

Comment: I like the `(( ${#array[@]} ))` to turn integers into `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks you named it "simulate shifting", because that's exactly what it is ;-)